# NicEdit with Codes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wysiwyg, nicedit

Im using NicEdit WYSIWYG editor for one of my projects.

http://nicedit.com

Problem im having is NicEdit want let me post any codes (HTML, CSS, PHP etc) to mysql database. other all saves fine in the database. Also i cannot find any 'code' button in NicEdit tool panel.

Here is the HTML code

```
<form action="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >


    <textarea name="area1" id="area1" cols=120></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btns" id="btns">Submi</button>
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
  $ptext = isset($_POST['area1'])?$_POST['area1']:""

  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tutorials(ptxt) VALUES ('$ptext'')") or die (mysqli_error());
```

is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the content of the editor in Javascript and manually send an ajax request to the server instead of submitting the form via the submit button.

```
var editorText = nicEditors.findEditor("area1").getContent();

var data = {
    area1: editorText
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/API/tutorials",
    data: data,
    complete: function(responseRaw){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because mysqli is trying to escape the characters.  A solution would be to create you own validation rules and pass the text through that.  Or just not escape the string, but that is a poor idea.

I would be pretty sure this is what it is, but I have always used PDO so I'm not very well rounded with mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping before you query the string. Needs to be done anyways for additional MySQL injection protection.

```
$ptext = $mysqli->real_escape_string($ptext);
```

Also an error was found in your query syntax caused by an additional quote. Change '$ptext'' to '$ptext' and the code should work fine.

If this don't work read up on the use of [nicInstance].saveContent(). Make a JS scipt execute it on submission before it posts. This syncs the textarea with the actual content in your nicEdit field.

http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API